# Calculate Grand Total Using Grouping SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have 1 table. Each subtotal in AVG_QTY_Total it will be same quantity as component material used in each MMODEL. However, for the Grand Total, I want to calculate each subtotal for 3 model. So if I sum up manually, it should be 240+500+1200 = 1940. How I can get it?

Below is my current query, result and expectation result.

Current query:

```
  select YYYYMM,(case when GROUPING(MODEL) = 0 and
                  GROUPING(MODEL_DESC) = 1 and 
                  GROUPING(MATERIAL) = 1 
             then 'Total ' + MODEL
             when GROUPING(MODEL) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(MODEL_DESC) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(MATERIAL) = 1 then 'Grand Total'
             else MODEL
        end) as MMODEL,
       MODEL_DESC, MATERIAL,
       sum(AVG_QTY)/COUNT(MODEL) as AVG_QTY_Total,
       sum(PACK_QTY) as PACK_QTY_Total,
       sum(PACK_AMT) as PACK_AMT_Total 
From [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING] 
group by grouping sets((YYYYMM,MODEL, MODEL_DESC ,MATERIAL),
                       (MODEL),
                       ()
                      );
```

Current Result :

```
YYYYMM  MMODEL  MODEL_DESC  MATERIAL    AVG_QTY_Total   PACK_QTY_Total  PACK_AMT_Total
201801  DE8     DE80001      A          240             20              3400
201801  DE8     DE80001      B          240             5               600
201801  DE8     DE80001      C          240             60              5000
NULL    Total DE8   NULL    NULL        240             85              9000
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      A          500             45              7600
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      B          500             10              1200
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      C          500             125             11000
NULL    Total DE8B  NULL    NULL        500             180             19800
201801  SF93    SF93005      A          1200            50              10200
201801  SF93    SF93005      B          1200            25              15000
201801  SF93    SF93005      C          1200            300             24000
NULL    Total SF93  NULL    NULL        1200            375             49200
NULL    Grand Total NULL    NULL        646             640             78000
```

Expectation Result :

```
YYYYMM  MMODEL  MODEL_DESC  MATERIAL    AVG_QTY_Total   PACK_QTY_Total  PACK_AMT_Total
201801  DE8     DE80001      A          240             20              3400
201801  DE8     DE80001      B          240             5               600
201801  DE8     DE80001      C          240             60              5000
NULL    Total DE8   NULL    NULL        240             85              9000
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      A          500             45              7600
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      B          500             10              1200
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      C          500             125             11000
NULL    Total DE8B  NULL    NULL        500             180             19800
201801  SF93    SF93005      A          1200            50              10200
201801  SF93    SF93005      B          1200            25              15000
201801  SF93    SF93005      C          1200            300             24000
NULL    Total SF93  NULL    NULL        1200            375             49200
NULL    Grand Total NULL    NULL        1940            640             78000
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION 1:**

Based on Gordon Linoff's answer, I managed to display result as expectation answer. I will try others answer too.

```
with t as (  select YYYYMM,(case when GROUPING(MODEL) = 0 and
                  GROUPING(MODEL_DESC) = 1 and 
                  GROUPING(MATERIAL) = 1 
             then MODEL
             when GROUPING(MODEL) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(MODEL_DESC) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(MATERIAL) = 1 then 'Grand Total'
             else MODEL
        end) as MMODEL,
       MODEL_DESC, MATERIAL,
       avg_qty as AVG_QTY_TT,
       sum(AVG_QTY)/COUNT(MODEL) as AVG_QTY_Total,
       sum(PACK_QTY) as PACK_QTY_Total,
       sum(PACK_AMT) as PACK_AMT_Total 
From [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING] 
group by grouping sets((YYYYMM,MODEL, MODEL_DESC ,MATERIAL,avg_qty),
                       (MODEL),
                       ()
                      )),
     m as (
      select  Sum(  AVG_QTY_TT)/ COUNT(DISTINCT MODEL_DESC ) AS cnt
      from t

     )
select YYYYMM,MMODEL,MODEL_DESC,MATERIAL,
       (case when mmodel = 'Grand Total' then  (select cnt from m)
             else avg_qty_total
        end) as AVG_QTY_Total,
        PACK_QTY_Total,PACK_AMT_Total
from t;
```

Comment: Just replicate the sample data on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can write our queries and test them easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use `grouping sets` for this . . . at least by itself.

Let me try to convince you that you *don't* want 1,940.  This is the sum of averages across three different groups.  Within each group, you are calculating the average.  So why sum them when you combine them?

You *could* try to adjust the values after the fact.  Essentially, run the query that you have, and do something like this:

```
with t as (<your query here>),
     m as (
      select count(distinct model) cnt
      from t
      where yyyymm is null
     )
select . . .,
       (case when mmodel = 'Grand Total' then AVG_QTY_Total * (select cnt from m)
             else avg_qty_total
        end)
from t;
```

On other caveat.  This will produce 1938, due to rounding issues with integers.  So, you also need to fix the arithmetic to use decimals/float rather than integers.

Comment: Will try your solution

Comment: I managed to display the result without converting the data types. I will update the query.

Comment: @SafwanChip . . . Cool.  I thought that would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The design of your table is not very clear to me. My understanding is that it looks like this:

```
YYYYMM  MMODEL  MODEL_DESC  MATERIAL    AVG_QTY_Total   PACK_QTY_Total  PACK_AMT_Total
201801  DE8     DE80001      A          240             20              3400
201801  DE8     DE80001      B          240             5               600
201801  DE8     DE80001      C          240             60              5000
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      A          500             45              7600
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      B          500             10              1200
201801  DE8B    DE8B002      C          500             125             11000
201801  SF93    SF93005      A          1200            50              10200
201801  SF93    SF93005      B          1200            25              15000
201801  SF93    SF93005      C          1200            300             24000
```

Since your AVG_QTY_Total is the same for each MMODEL, you can simply identify theme with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MMODEL, AVG_QTY_Total
FROM [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING]
```

You can also add the column `YYYYMM` if you want to do it over several days.

```
SELECT DISTINCT YYYYMM, MMODEL, AVG_QTY_Total
FROM [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING]
```

Then if you want the grand total you can simply wrap the query above in another which would do the sum:

```
SELECT MMODEL, SUM(AVG_QTY_Total)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT YYYYMM, MMODEL, AVG_QTY_Total
    FROM [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING]
) TMP
GROUP BY MMODEL
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Im sorry bro. If you see my table carefully, the table should have subtotal and grand total in it.

Comment: Ok got it, it's a strange design. Ideally you would store those in a separate table. Then why not querying on your table like this: `SELECT MMODEL, SUM(AVG_QTY_Total) FROM [SQLDB1].[dbo].[PACKING] WHERE MMODEL LIKE 'Total%' GROUP BY MMODEL`

Comment: yes. It should be stored in separate table. But, I just recreate and combine into a new table that same as original table just to show my problem.

Comment: @SafwanChip that makes it more confusing than anything else. Can I recommend you to describe the different tables and their content separately in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
   WITH Group_Ttl AS 
(SELECT 
  YYYYMM, MMODEL,
MAX(AVG_QTY_Total) AS AVG_QTY_Total,
SUM(PACK_QTY_Total)  AS PACK_QTY_Total,
SUM(PACK_AMT_Total)  AS PACK_AMT_Total

FROM PACKING
GROUP BY YYYYMM, MMODEL
),Grandttl AS 
(
  SELECT
  SUM(AVG_QTY_Total)  AS AVG_QTY_Total,
    SUM(PACK_QTY_Total) AS PACK_QTY_Total,
    SUM(PACK_AMT_Total) AS PACK_AMT_Total

  FROM Group_Ttl
 )
 ,Rslt AS 
 (

    SELECT 
     YYYYMM,
     MMODEL,
     MODEL_DESC,
     MATERIAL,
     AVG_QTY_Total,
     PACK_QTY_Total,
     PACK_AMT_Total ,
     AVG_QTY_Total AS SortColumn
   FROM PACKING 

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
     NULL,
    'Total ' + MMODEL,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     AVG_QTY_Total,
     PACK_QTY_Total,
     PACK_AMT_Total ,
    AVG_QTY_Total AS SortColumn
   FROM Group_Ttl

   UNION ALL

 SELECT 
     NULL,
     'Grand Total',
     NULL,
     NULL,
     AVG_QTY_Total,
     PACK_QTY_Total,
     PACK_AMT_Total,
     PACK_QTY_Total*PACK_AMT_Total AS SortColumn
   FROM Grandttl


  )

  SELECT 
     YYYYMM,
     MMODEL,
     MODEL_DESC,
     MATERIAL,
     AVG_QTY_Total,
     PACK_QTY_Total,
     PACK_AMT_Total  
 FROM Rslt
 ORDER  BY SortColumn,PACK_QTY_Total
```

[sample link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00041/46)